# Bracha on Synthetic Smells

Tags: halacha, smell, blessing

What is or is there a Bracha on Synthetically developed smells in the halachic literature and what is the source as I would Imagine artificial scents are a recent phenomenon?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64269

Answer (score 9):

Rav Shlomo Zalman Aurbach contended that no bracha should be made on synthetic smells.

However, most poskim disagreed and said that these smells warrant the standard bracha of Borei Minei Vesamim.

[Source](http://e.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/shiur.asp?id=12746)

Comment: The link to the source doesn't work. Do you have an up-to-date link please?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I am not sure what was the original link but [this](http://halachayomit.co.il/en/Default.aspx?HalachaID=3048&PageIndex=5) might interest you