# What bracha should be made when smelling soap?

Tags: blessing, smell

I'm assuming that when one showers / bathes and uses a bar of soap but isn't concentrating on the smell, he would not need to make a bracha. (There is a similar  M.Y. question about needing to make a bracha when entering a coffee shop.)

However, if one intentionally smells a bar of soap to enjoy its fragrance, what bracha should he make? Body soap has a combination of some natural products - sometimes aloe (a "fruit" plant - normally would have the bracha for smelling fruits); could be honey, might be oatmeal, wheat germ, and mostly it has chemical fragrances (is there any bracha ever made on synthetic fragrances?)

In short, what bracha should you make on bar soap?

Comment: Probably akin to a *brachah* on *mugmar* which a *brachah* isn’t made ([OC 217:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.217.3?with=all&lang=bi)).

Comment: @Oliver I am unfamiliar with that term. However, the end of the paragraph says ולא על שמן העשוי להעביר את הזוהמא - Not on oil made to remove sweat. Soap is similar. So I think this may answer the question. You probably should post that as an answer, unless you're uncertain.

Comment: I’d compare your quote from סעיף א to your first paragraph. OTOH when you soap/lather to be clean *and* to be redolent of its fragrance my impression is that it’s closer to scented detergent.

Comment: I learned there was no bracha on artificial smells, only on natural ones, i.e., no bracha on perfume for instance, see also [here](http://halachayomit.co.il/en/Default.aspx?HalachaID=3048&PageIndex=5) and [there](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=12746)

Comment: related: [Bracha on Synthetic Smells](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13508/11501)

Comment: There has to be an ikar(an actual herb) in the soap and it has to be made for smelling; an added ingredient that's tafel(say lavender; for example) to the main product(soap) wouldn't require a bracha. See Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 216:6  and Ba'er Heitev 13 there and 217:2.

Comment: @Oliver Hi, we do bless on mugmar; just not when it's absorbed into something else or for the purpose of adding a scent onto clothes(like detergent). See Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 216:12.